# IPv6 not working with ping or http

Tags: networking, ipv6

I have a machine that wont communicate over IPv6.

To demonstrate, the example here makes use of both Ping/Ping6 and opening Websites(IPv4 and IPv6).

Example:

```
host google.com
```

i get

```
google.com has address 172.217.168.78 google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:400a:803::200e
```

**Test1**

ping 172.217.168.78 **OK**

ping6 2a00:1450:400a:803::200e **FAILURE**

**Test2**

firefox http://172.217.168.78 **Test1**

firefox http://2a00:1450:400a:803::200e **FAILURE**

**Question**

is this related to my settings within the OS or is this related to either my local network or the internet provider settings?
i dont understand why i both can ping and load google for example over ipv4 but ipv6 will do.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and I strongly suspect the OS settings, or even the network chipset driver,  as all other machines on the same network are working fine with Ipv6, but not that single machine.

Answer (score 0):

This could technically be blocked by your firewall configuration, but it's more likely your router. There is an outside chance it's the ISP but quite unlikely these days. Router configuration may be limited (if it's ISP-provided), even so it might be worth looking at. Try [Kitz](https://kitz.co.uk/routers/) and their [wiki](https://wiki.kitz.co.uk/index.php/Main_Page)